# Создать словарь из многомерного (вложенного) списка

Tags: python

Имеется многомерный список

```
a_list = [[1,0,3,4],[5,1,7,8],[9,2,2,4],[8,3,6,5],[2,4,5,6]]
```

Список необходимо преобразовать в словарь который для ключа выбирает второй элемент вложенного списка,а значением остальные элементы списка. Например для первого списка `[1,0,3,4]` ключем в словаре будет `key = 0` , значение `value = [1,3,4]`
Итоговый словарь будет иметь вид

```
a_dict = {0:[1,3,4],
          1:[5,7,8],
          2:[9,2,4],
          3:[8,6,5],
          4:[2,5,6],}
```

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать так:

```py
a_list = [[1,0,3,4],[5,1,7,8],[9,2,2,4],[8,3,6,5],[2,4,5,6]]
a_dict = {el.pop(1): el for el in a_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм решения:

- воспользуйтесь "dictionary comprehension" - `res = {key: value for ...}`
- в качестве ключа можно использовать метод `list.pop()`, который удаляет элемент списка и возвращает его

Если правильно реализовать данный алгоритм - у вас получится короткое и эффективное однострочное решение.

PS если приведете в вопросе собственные попытки решения, тогда и я смогу показать реализацию алгоритма в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот

```
a_list = [[1,0,3,4],[5,1,7,8],[9,2,2,4],[8,3,6,5],[2,4,5,6]]
a_dict_ = {}
for a in a_list: # перебор значений списка
    key = a[1] # ключ
    arr = [a[0]] + a[2:] # значение
    a_dict[key] = arr # добавление
print(a_dict)
```